# how to find how many rows effected by select query from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to find how many rows affected when I fire a select query from C#. without insert data into dataset or datatable.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString; //get connection string Web.config

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);

//define Select Query
SqlCommand slct = new SqlCommand("select * From [dbo].[userdetail] where 1=1", con);
int noRows;

//open connection and execute query
con.Open();
noRows = slct.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

//define Select Query
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("select * From [dbo].[userdetail] where 1=0", con);

//open connection and execute query
con.Open();
noRows = select.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: In that case, you need to use `SELECT COUNT(*) .....` and then use `select.ExecuteScalar()` to get back the count of rows

Comment: If you retrieve the dataset from the database you can count the rows in the dataset retrieved

Comment: You need to define "affected". Because if you meant "selected" then it means to count the results like commented above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all for your current query use `ExecuteReader()` and while reading the loop saying below keep a counter

```
int count = 0;

while(rdr.Read())
{
  count++;
}
```

Else, use a scalar query like below and use `ExecuteScalar()` function

```
select count(*) From [dbo].[userdetail] 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) From [dbo].[userdetail]", con);

// open connection and execute query
con.Open();
int noRows = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```